Aligning Footnotes in a LaTeX Table
I am working on a document that includes a table with specific model descriptions as footnotes. I've been trying to format these footnotes so that they are clear and professional, but I'm facing some challenges with their alignment and readability.
Here there is the code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Robustness Test: Differences (percentage points) between Model 1, 2, 3, and 4}
\label{tab:model_differences}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{15}{c}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Model 2-1} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Model 3-1} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Model 4-1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11} \cmidrule(lr){12-16}
Models & MAE & MSE & RMSE & R$^2$ & MAPE & MAE & MSE & RMSE & R$^2$ & MAPE & MAE & MSE & RMSE & R$^2$ & MAPE \\ 
\midrule
ET        & -1.14 & -1.82 & -0.92 & 0.00 & -4.76 & -0.51 & -0.86 & -0.44 & 0.00 & -3.57 & -3.57 & -5.85 & -2.96 & 2.90 & -4.76 \\
LightGBM  & -3.59 & -4.73 & -113.0 & 3.03 & -4.76 & -2.17 & -4.64 & -111.0 & 3.03 & -0.00 & -8.07 & -7.13 & -172.0 & 4.55 & -4.76 \\
XGBoost   & -4.61 & -6.36 & -159.0 & 3.13 & -8.70 & -2.97 & -4.44 & -110.0 & 1.56 & -4.35 & -4.69 & -5.72 & -143.0 & 3.13 & -4.35 \\
BRR       & -1.61 & -1.99 & 65.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -0.31 & -0.65 & -21.00 & 2.63 & -0.00 & -1.57 & -2.05 & -66.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 \\
ENR       & -1.46 & -1.76 & -61.00 & 3.57 & -2.70 & -0.34 & -0.76 & -27.00 & 0.00 & -0.00 & -1.46 & -1.97 & -69.00 & 3.57 & -2.70 \\
LASSO     & -1.56 & -1.91 & -62.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -0.31 & -0.60 & -19.00 & 0.00 & -2.86 & -1.52 & -1.95 & -62.60 & 4.82 & -1.57 \\
LR        & -1.59 & -1.99 & -65.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -1.57 & -2.05 & -67.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -1.57 & -2.05 & -67.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Model 1: Relies solely on market features and omits physical and transitional risk factors.
\item Model 2: Integrates market features with the Physical Risk Indicator (PRI).
\item Model 3: Incorporates market features with the Transition Risk Indicator (TRI).
\item Model 4: Combines climate change risk variables (PRI and TRI) with market features.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

output


Off-topic: (a) If you're going to employ a threeparttable environment, do please place the \caption directive inside the threeparttable environment. (The three formal parts of a threeparttable environment are the \caption directive, a tabular (or similar) environment, and the tablenotes environment.) (b) If the table is the only object on the landscape-oriented page, you shouldn't use the [h] positioning specifier, as the table will look better being placed in the middle of the page.

The immediate cause of the formatting issues you're experiencing is a combination of (a) the \centering directive and (b) the improper \item-related syntax in the tablenotes environment.
Since you aren't using any \tnote directives, employing the threeparttable package machinery seems to be too much of a good thing. I think that (a) not using a \centering directive, (b) employing a tabular* environment (with a target width of \linewidth), and (c) placing the four-line legend below the table should be good enough.
A separate comment: Aligning the numbers in the 15 data columns on their decimal markers as well as employing proper math-minus symbols instead of simple dashes to denote negative numbers should make the numbers easier to take in.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,  
              justification=raggedright,
              labelsep=newline,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newcommand{\mcv}[1]{\multicolumn{5}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}  %[h]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Robustness Test: Differences (percentage points) between Models 1, 2, 3, and 4}
\label{tab:model_differences}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
   l *{3}{T{-1.2} T{-1.2} T{-3.2} T{1.2} T{-1.2}} }
\toprule
Models
& \mcv{Model $2-1$} & \mcv{Model $3-1$} & \mcv{Model $4-1$} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-11} \cmidrule{12-16}
       & {MAE} & {MSE} & {RMSE} & {R$^2$} & {MAPE} 
       & {MAE} & {MSE} & {RMSE} & {R$^2$} & {MAPE} 
       & {MAE} & {MSE} & {RMSE} & {R$^2$} & {MAPE} \\ 
\midrule
ET        & -1.14 & -1.82 &   -0.92 & 0.00 & -4.76 & -0.51 & -0.86 &   -0.44 & 0.00 & -3.57 & -3.57 & -5.85 &   -2.96 & 2.90 & -4.76 \\
LightGBM  & -3.59 & -4.73 & -113.0  & 3.03 & -4.76 & -2.17 & -4.64 & -111.0  & 3.03 & -0.00 & -8.07 & -7.13 & -172.0  & 4.55 & -4.76 \\
XGBoost   & -4.61 & -6.36 & -159.0  & 3.13 & -8.70 & -2.97 & -4.44 & -110.0  & 1.56 & -4.35 & -4.69 & -5.72 & -143.0  & 3.13 & -4.35 \\
BRR       & -1.61 & -1.99 &   65.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -0.31 & -0.65 &  -21.00 & 2.63 & -0.00 & -1.57 & -2.05 &  -66.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 \\
ENR       & -1.46 & -1.76 &  -61.00 & 3.57 & -2.70 & -0.34 & -0.76 &  -27.00 & 0.00 & -0.00 & -1.46 & -1.97 &  -69.00 & 3.57 & -2.70 \\
LASSO     & -1.56 & -1.91 &  -62.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -0.31 & -0.60 &  -19.00 & 0.00 & -2.86 & -1.52 & -1.95 &  -62.60 & 4.82 & -1.57 \\
LR        & -1.59 & -1.99 &  -65.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -1.57 & -2.05 &  -67.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 & -1.57 & -2.05 &  -67.00 & 2.63 & -2.86 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip \small
\obeylines
Model 1: Relies solely on market features and omits physical and transitional risk factors.
Model 2: Integrates market features with the Physical Risk Indicator (PRI).
Model 3: Incorporates market features with the Transition Risk Indicator (TRI).
Model 4: Combines climate change risk variables (PRI and TRI) with market features.

\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

